# How to set multiple class properties to properties of one object

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

The problem I'm facing is that I don't want have to call a function which returns both properties twice, instead I basically want to do this:

```
class xy {
   x: number;
   y: number;

   constructor (arg) {
       { this.x, this.y } = foo(arg); //this function returns an object with two properties
   }
```

}

Instead of this:

```
class xy {
   x: number;
   y: number;

   constructor (arg) {
       this.x = foo(arg).x;
       this.y = foo(arg).y;
   }
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign(this, foo(args)` this will assign all properties returned by `foo` so take care with it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `foo(arg)` returns an object with only `x` and `y` properties:

```
class xy {
   x: number;
   y: number;

   constructor (arg) {
       Object.assign(this, foo(arg));
   }
}
```

If `foo` might return more properties, you'll need to manually grab the properties:

```
class xy {
   x: number;
   y: number;

   constructor (arg) {
       const {x, y} = foo(arg);
       Object.assign(this, {x, y});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, you *could* use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), but beware that it assigns **all** of the (own, enumerable) properties in the object returned by `foo`.

To avoid that, you can use destructuring:

```
const {x, y} = foo(arg);
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
```

It doesn't gain you much, but...

You can combine the approaches:

```
const {x, y} = foo(arg);
Object.assign(this, {x, y});
```

...at the cost of (in theory) a temporary object allocation. (I say "in theory" since the JavaScript engine can optimize it out. But I don't know that it would.)

---

It's for situations like this that [this proposal was put forward](https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation). Sadly, it hasn't gotten any traction to speak of with the committee. If that proposal were to go forward, you'd be able to do this:

```
// NOT STANDARD JAVASCRIPT (the proposal hasn't even been accepted for Stage 0)
this.{x, y} = foo(arg);
```